# Package not found even though it can be seen with pip list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

If I do a `pip list` in my virtualenv I see that ibm-cos-sdk(ibm_boto3) is installed.

However, when I run my application I get this error:

```py
(venv36) Pauls-MBP-3:sdk-python-config-test me$ nosetests --process-timeout=1200
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ModuleNotFoundError (No module named 'ibm_boto3')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 675, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/me/git/sdk-python-config-test/cos_config_test/test_config_sdk.py", line 3, in <module>
    import ibm_boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibm_boto3'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

What causes this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ nosetests --process-timeout=1200

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
```

You don't run your application — you run `nosetests`. Here we see that you run it from the global `site-packages` hence it uses a global Python, not Python from your virtual environment. And global Python cannot find your module because it's install in the virtual environment.

Install `nose` in the same virtual environment to run it with Python from the virtualenv.